# Profile is returning null after login

Tags: dart, flutter

I have developed separate class to call APIs. In that process I have developed separate class for Web API call, Model class and one login screen. From login screen I am calling API class and my login is successful from that. But I want to retrieve profile data from there. 
Which is returning null to me.

For your reference here is the code for login Class code from where I calling API class

```
    //Login Button
    final loginButton = ButtonTheme(
      minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-40,
      height: 50.0,
      child: new RaisedButton(
          color: blueColor,
          onPressed: (){
            foo();
          },
          child: Text('Log In',
            style: styleLoginButton,
          ),
          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))
          ),
      );

     void foo() async{
      print('foo called');
      final profile = await LoginAPI().profileGetRequest();
      print(profile.firstName);
    }
```

API Class

```
class LoginAPI {

  Future<Profile> profileGetRequest() async {
    try {
      String strUserName = "test@tester.ch";
      String strPassword = "tester";
      String basicAuth = 'Basic ' +
          base64Encode(utf8.encode('$strUserName:$strPassword'));
      String strURL = Config.API_URL + Config.PROFILE;
      final response = await http.get(
        strURL,
        headers: {
          "Authorization": basicAuth,
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
        return Profile.fromJson(responseJson);
      }
      else {
        return Profile.fromError(json.decode(response.body));
      }
    } catch (exception) {
      print('exception $exception');
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Profile Model

```
class Profile{
  final int userId;
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final String gender;


  Profile(
      this.userId,
      this.firstName,
      this.lastName,
      this.gender
  );

  //Profile when Error received
  Profile.fromError(Map<String, dynamic> json):
        userId = 0,
        firstName = null,
        lastName = null,
        gender = null;

  //Profile when No Error Received
  Profile.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json):
        userId = json['userId'],
        firstName = json['firstName'],
        lastName = json['lastName'],
        gender = json['gender'];
}
```

Comment: What is the value of your response.body ?

Comment: @SaedNabil I am getting following response: 
{id: 1, userId: 1, visibilityLevel: PUBLIC, firstname: Chandra, lastname: prakash, gender: m, genderEnum: MALE, birthday: 24.09.1989, age: 29, mailAddress: cp@test.com}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys of your map is not matching you have to change your keys like this

```
firstName ---> firstname
lastName ---> lastname
```

use the code below

```
//Profile when No Error Received
  Profile.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json):
        userId = json['userId'],
        firstName = json['firstname'],
        lastName = json['lastname'],
        gender = json['gender'];
```